# How to check a dropdownlist exist or not in C# aspnet

Tags: c#

How can I check a dropdownlist is existed on a page or not? I want to validate a certain condition when there is no dropdownlist found on the page. If it cant find any dropdownlist, it will not run the code `string test = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();`

What i've tried:

```
if (DropDownList1 not exist) 
{ 
    //
}
string test = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
```

Comment: Page? Exist? Please elaborate your context. You can perform a null-check using: `if (DropDownList1 is null)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (DropDownList1 != null) 
{ 
    string test = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
if (DropDownList1 == null) 
{ 
   //Do stuff
   return;
}
string test = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
```